# WCF 4.0 - Get Parameter from URL or POST Body

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I have a WCF endpoint and I have setup my URI Template as such:

```
UriTemplate = "?token={token}"
```

If the token parameter is not in the URL, I want it to attempt to pull it from the POST body.

I am testing my POST calls and putting the token in the URL works great, but fails if I put it in the POST body instead.

Is there any way to handle this? I was doing it before using a ServiceAuthorizationManager, however, there wasn't a great way to send back friendly error messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get access to the RequestBody as shown below:

```
OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.GetBody<string>();
```

Hope that helps you :)